# How to generate a default index.html for React 16 using Webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

*NB. I know how to achieve my goal. The question is not "**how** to do X" but rather "how to **smoothly** do X". I'm looking for a like-a-boss'y way to reach the result.*

I'm setting up a new React application based on Webpack. For educational purpose, I want to do that from scratch. At the current stage, I'm transpiling all the files correctly, only missing *index.html*.

According to [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#setting-up-htmlwebpackplugin) I may use a plugin to generate a default *index.html* and customize it using [certain options](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options).

The plugin generates only a default document not allowing me to inject a snippet like `<div id="app"></div>` into it. However, bootstraping a React application is done in relation to such an element, as shown below.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavBar />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Now, I understand that I can use the option *templateContent* but it's a lot of work for such a simple injection. There's also the option *template* which might be used with [HTML Webpack template](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template) but that doesn't seem to be much less work neither [as exemplified here](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template#example).

It seems to me that React, being such a popular library, should enable a simpler way to generate a default document that contains the bootstraping element(s) injectable through a simple option. So I expect that there's a neat and proper way to generate an *index.html* file containing a DIV (or series of DIVs) with ID(s) passed in as a parameter.

Is there such a method and what does it look like?

*edit*

My config file was requested. Below's the relevant part. It's applying HTML Webpack template and does the job. However, the question's whether it can be done without it, using the plugin only (or even better - without even using the plugin).

```
plugins: [
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: "Reactify Poc",
    favicon: "",
    inject: false,
    template: HtmlWebpackTemplate,
    appMountIds: ["nav", "app"]
  })
],
```

Comment: have you looked into `create-react-app`, it takes care of a lot of the initialization needed to set up your first react project - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Yes. That would defeat the purpose. (*For educational purpose, I want to do that from scratch.*) Also, I'm not sure how updated it's now and I hear that e.g. *webpack-serve* is recommended now instead of *webpack-dev-server*. So your hint is good but in this case, I want to do it the hard way, to learn. (It might be that the hard part implies that I'll have to do it using the templates, of course. But I hope that someone has a neat tip.)

Comment: `HTML webpack Plugin` will do the work for you. Can you provide your webpack config here

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I haven't found a way to do that using the plugin (except playing with the templates, as mentioned). I've posted the relevant part of my config.